# combining two set of data in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to combine two sets of data.

```
var a = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'foo' },
  { Id: 2, Name: 'boo' }];

var b = [{ Id: 3, Name: 'doo' },
        { Id: 4, Name: 'coo' }];
```

Most of question here i found is only a normal array.

I've tried `Object.assign(a, b);` but it only returns the b value.

The a and b data is from the server side.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `const c = [...a, ...b]` or `const c = a.concat(b);`

Comment: let newArray = a.concat(b);

Comment: oh god. just a simple syntax. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try array concat

```js
var a = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'foo' },
  { Id: 2, Name: 'boo' }];

var b = [{ Id: 3, Name: 'doo' },
        { Id: 4, Name: 'coo' }];
let c = a.concat(b);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spread syntax

```
var a = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'foo' },
  { Id: 2, Name: 'boo' }];

var b = [{ Id: 3, Name: 'doo' },
        { Id: 4, Name: 'coo' }];

c = [...a, ...b];
```

Note: Spread syntax is not supported by all browsers , its ok if you use es6/5 compiler though like babel. See [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Another option is